# There is a problem for updating database using forms.form in Django and I want use only one 'update' button to update many database data

Tags: python, django, database, forms, button

what I want do make is that

show the existing data in the database to a user through HTML page.
let a user update the existing data if he wants to do.

Promblem 1> the problem is that,when running my code, a user input the new data and clicked 'update' button, but the update did not work.

I don't know whether it is the reason or not, anyway, when I put 'def show_data' and 'def input' together, updating did work well. However 'def show_data'and 'def input' should be separate.

'def show_data' : it is for saving the data from excel file into the database using pandas

'def input': it is for receiving the input data from a user and updating the existing data with the input data

Promblem 2> There are many 'update' button in the web page. I want to make only one 'update' button at the bottom of web page for updating all data user input into the database.

Please refer to the below codes and result image.

<forms.py>

```
from django import forms 
from report.models import Upload, Memo

class InputForm(forms.Form):
    item_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    memo = forms.CharField()
    user_input = forms.CharField()
```

<models.py>

```
from django.db import models

class Memo(models.Model):
    memo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_input = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.memo} | {self.user_input} "
```

<views.py>

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import UploadFileForm, InputForm
from .models import Memo
import pandas as pd

   
#this is for saving the data from excel file into the database using pandas.

def show_data(request):
df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\....\myproject\media\upload\sample_file.xlsx')
df_cp=df
analysis_with_list=df_cp.query('출금액!=0')
analysis_with_list=analysis_with_list.loc[:,['적요','출금액']]
analysis_with_list=analysis_with_list.groupby(by=['적요']).sum()
analysis_with_list.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
           
ss=[]
for i in range(0,len(analysis_with_list)):
     st = (analysis_with_list['적요'][i])
     ss.append(st)
for i in range(0,len(analysis_with_list)):
     Memo.objects.create(memo=ss[i])
        
return render(request,'report/show_data.html',context)

# this is for receiving the input data from a user and updating the existing data with the input data

def input(request):
    items = Memo.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get the ID from the form data
            item_id = request.POST.get('id')

            # Fetch the item by ID
            item = Memo.objects.get(id=item_id)

            # Update the item with the new data from the form
            item.memo = form.cleaned_data['memo']
            item.user_input = form.cleaned_data['user_input']

            # Update other fields as needed

            item.save()
            return redirect('input')  # Redirect to the table display page after updating

    else:
        form = InputForm()

    return render(request, 'report/input.html', {'items': items, 'form': form})
```

<input.html>

```
<!-- update_table_template.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update Table Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>지출 내역에 맞는 지출 용도를 입력해 주세요</h2>
    <h3>(생활비, 식비, 공과금, 자녀용돈 등 본인이 원하는 카테고리를 만들어 주세요)</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>적요(저장내역)</th>
            <th>구분(저장내역)</th>
            <th>변경사항 입력</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.memo }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.user_input }}</td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ item.id }}">
                    <input type="text" name="memo" value="{{ item.memo }}">
                    <input type="text" name="user_input" value="{{ item.user_input }}">
                    <!-- Add other fields as needed -->
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <a href="{% url 'analysis' %}"><h2>누르면 지출 항목 분석 내역을 보실 수 있습니다. </h2></a>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]